# Salvattore plugin ignores divs with display: none;

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am using http://salvattore.com to create a tiled grid layout. Everything works fine until I use the plugin inside a div that is displayed: none;

The plugin will completely ignore it, it will also cause problems on Safari and break the website as it shows an error related to :before and :after not found "which what the plugin uses". Is there a workaround? to make the plugin work on div's that are not displayed yet?

I have put together testing site here: http://loai.directory/beta

As you will see there are two .grid div's one is shown by default and the other one is hidden. The reason I need that div hidden is because I want to use it as a popup, so it will only show when triggered.

Comment: IMHO, this is more of a bug report for the creators of Salvattore than an actual question.

Comment: Thank you @Marventus I have submitted the problem to them, will submit an answer here just in-case someone might be looking for the same problem in the future.